# React-admin: how to hide refresh button from AppBar?

Tags: react-admin, admin-on-rest

I'm creating admin ui based on react-admin and currently searching for a solution to hide the refresh button from the `AppBar`. 
Disabling export button was trivial (`exporter={false}`). Is there anything equally simple for RefreshButton? I couldn't find any working solution.

My React-admin version: 2.9.3

I know you could customize the actions with 'actions' prop on `List` component, but this seems to be outdated since the Refresh button was moved to the app bar..

I could provide the code to my custom `AppBar` if needed.

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple solution, the presence of the LoadingIndicator component is not configured in AppBar:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/AppBar.js

You can implement your AppBar component and then connect it to AppLayout:

```
// Layout.js

import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import AppBarEx from './components/AppBarEx';

const AppLayout = (props) => ( 
  <Layout
    {...props}
    appBar={AppBarEx}
  />
);

export default AppLayout;

// AppBarEx.js

import React, { Children, cloneElement } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import MuiAppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { toggleSidebar as toggleSidebarAction } from 'ra-core';
import { UserMenu, Headroom } from 'react-admin';

const styles = theme =>
    createStyles({
        toolbar: {
            paddingRight: 24,
        },
        menuButton: {
            marginLeft: '0.5em',
            marginRight: '0.5em',
        },
        menuButtonIconClosed: {
            transition: theme.transitions.create(['transform'], {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
            }),
            transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
        },
        menuButtonIconOpen: {
            transition: theme.transitions.create(['transform'], {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
            }),
            transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
        },
        title: {
            flex: 1,
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
    });

const AppBar = ({
    children,
    classes,
    className,
    logo,
    logout,
    open,
    title,
    toggleSidebar,
    userMenu,
    width,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Headroom>
        <MuiAppBar
            className={className}
            color="secondary"
            position="static"
            {...rest}
        >
            <Toolbar
                disableGutters
                variant={width === 'xs' ? 'regular' : 'dense'}
                className={classes.toolbar}
            >
                <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={toggleSidebar}
                    className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
                >
                    <MenuIcon
                        classes={{
                            root: open
                                ? classes.menuButtonIconOpen
                                : classes.menuButtonIconClosed,
                        }}
                    />
                </IconButton>
                {Children.count(children) === 0 ? (
                    <Typography
                        variant="title"
                        color="inherit"
                        className={classes.title}
                        id="react-admin-title"
                    />
                ) : (
                    children
                )}
                {cloneElement(userMenu, { logout })}
            </Toolbar>
        </MuiAppBar>
    </Headroom>
);

AppBar.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    logout: PropTypes.element,
    open: PropTypes.bool,
    title: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element]).isRequired,
    toggleSidebar: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    userMenu: PropTypes.node,
    width: PropTypes.string,
};

AppBar.defaultProps = {
    userMenu: <UserMenu />,
};

const enhance = compose(
    connect(
        state => ({
            locale: state.i18n.locale, // force redraw on locale change
        }),
        {
            toggleSidebar: toggleSidebarAction,
        }
    ),
    withStyles(styles),
    withWidth()
);

export default enhance(AppBar);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who just want to hide refresh button, I accomplished it by having my own custom theme (for more info check react admin [theming documentation page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#writing-a-custom-theme)).

For example, I have two themes, light and dark one.
Here is the example of how I managed to target refresh button with css:

```
 export const lightTheme = {
    palette: {
        background: {
            paper: "#fff",
            default: "#fff"
        },
        primary: {
            main: '#607D8B'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#607D8B'
        },
        sidebarColor: '#E7ECEE',
        menuItemsColor: '#4B6471'
    },

// overrides default theme css
    overrides: {
        // targeting refresh button
        RaAppBar: {
            toolbar: {
                '& button': {
                    '&:not(:nth-child(1))': {
                        display: 'none'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It is not pretty way, but for some reason, If you use :nth-child(1) it targets both: drawer (first button in app bar) and custom profile button which is last in html DOM (See the image below).

[targeting using :nth-child(1) IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pr7z.png)

Because of that, I come to an idea to use **:not((:nth-child(1))** and it solves the problem if your goal is to hide it, but you can also use other css properties to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Also less than ideal, but I targeted it with the "Refresh" aria-label. Not an approach I'd typically take, but it's the only thing distinguishing the button in React Admin's CSS.

```
header.MuiPaper-root button[aria-label="Refresh"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you know react admin uses mui and we can override the RaLoadingIndicator in theme but this solution will hide the RaLoadingIndicator from all pages.

```
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  createTheme,
  experimental_sx as sx,
} from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = {
  ...defaultTheme,
    RaLoadingIndicator: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: sx({
          display: "none",
        }),
      },
    },
  },
 
};
```